# add elements in fragment's view android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android, I have a fragment which have this XML code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearRoot"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cv"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/person_name"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="bonjour"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/person_age"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                    android:text="ce test a réussi"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

With this one, I want to add several CardView Dynamically.So, as a test, I'm trying to add a second CardView in the LinearLayout this way :

```
    public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout ll;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
        ll = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearRoot);
        CardView cv = new CardView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ll.addView(cv);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

but it does nothing at all. I'm wondering what is the right way to do this.

Comment: try adding some layout height and width for your dynamically created cardview, you will see it.

Comment: yes, thanks
I'm feeling really stupid now... x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add LayoutParams (width, height) in order to actually show your CardView

```
cv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(20,20));
```

for example with 20dp width and height